# MySQL Workbench setting column as UNIQUE, but should it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

For the life of me, I can't, for one:

Figure out why MySQL complains about this `INSERT` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mangobase`.`profile_education` (
  `id` TINYINT UNIQUE UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxx',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

The complaint:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 91: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxx',' at line 2
```

Removal of `UNIQUE` in the `id` column definition allows this statement to go through without error. But, secondly, why is it being created in the first place? I am not designating it as a unique column in MySQL Workbench (UQ designates a column as unique):

[image: Table as defined in MySQL Workbench]

I have other tables defined exactly the same way (same field names, definition attributes) where MySQL WB isn't assigning `UNIQUE` to the column definition. It would be tedious indeed to need to manually edit the sql script each time I want to update the database during production.

1. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking that's causing MySQL WB to assign `UNIQUE` to this column?
2. Why is 'UNIQUE` even seemingly illegal here in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `unique` between `tinyint` and `unsigned`.  Those are both part of the type definition.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mangobase`.`profile_education` (
  `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxx',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

EDIT:

You do not need to designate a primary key as unique.  I would write this as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mangobase`.`profile_education` (
  `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxx'
);
```

I see no reason to have a default value for a primary key.  Perhaps you also want it to be auto-incrementing as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see. That makes perfect sense too (that column attributes shouldn't be mixed in with the type definition). I guess workbench doesn't know that, which is odd because it would seem this behavior would have been picked up on a while ago and corrected by now. Do you happen to know if it's even necessary to designate a primary key as unique?